# prove $-a = (-1)a$ ? I've done two possible proofs. Which is valid if at all?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm self studying math. I'm just starting "A Survey of Modern Algebra" by Birkhoff and Mac Lane because I thought the proof section of this book was more clear than Shilov's first chapter in "Introduction to Real and Complex Analysis". I'm pretty new to proofs. I know this is perhaps very simple but I need some feedback since there are no answers in the back and I have no one else to talk to about proofs.
Are either of these acceptable? Both? Thank you for your patience.

*page 8 Problem 3 (d) : Prove $-a = (-1)a$*

**proof one**

let $a = 1 $

$-1 = -1(1) $ by substitution

$-1 = -1 $ by unity

**proof two**

since $a = 1a$

$(-1)a = (-1)a$ by substitution on the left

Comment: The first one assumes what you are trying to prove and doesn't prove the statement.

Comment: Are you sure that that's the correct statement? Instead of $-a=(-1)a$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oops. books confirms what you wrote.

Comment: Your second proof doesn't address the initial hypothesis.

Comment: The first one is nonsense and the second one is nonsense.

Comment: I came from your link in second question ...But I didn't laugh like you said there.everyone do need time to understand mathematics at beginning ...it is very good yo see you are self studying and improving...good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your proofs are actually proofs.

Note that $ -a$ is the additive opposite of $ a $ Therefore to show that $(-1)a=-a$, we have to prove that $$(-1)a+a=0$$

Since $a=(1)a$, we have $$ (-1)a + a = (-1)a + (1)a = (-1+1)a = 0a =0$$

Thus $(-1)a$ is indeed the additive inverse of $a$, that is $(-1)a=-a$

Answer (score 2):

They are both wrong. The first one is nonsense. In second one, you don't even deduce what you were supposed to deduce.

Note that\begin{align}(-1)a+a&=(-1)a+1a\\&=\bigl((-1)+1\bigr)a\\&=0\times a=0.\end{align} Therefore, $(-1)a=-a$, since each element has one and only one inverse for the addition.

Comment: and this works because on the other side +a - a = 0 and by the transitive axiom?

Comment: @José: although implicit in your answer, you may want to emphasize what $-a$ means, because I feel like OP is missing the point.

Comment: @PossiblyDakota It works because$$-a=-a+0=-a+\bigl(a+(-1)a\bigr)=(-a+a)+(-1)a=0+(-1)a=(-1)a.$$

Comment: Of course one has also to prove that $0a=0$

Comment: @egreg Of course. I suppose that at that point of the book, that has already been proven.

Comment: @egreg There is a full proof of this on page 5