# prove that $X^2 \equiv 35 \pmod{100}$ has no solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

This problem is from  'A Survey of Modern Algebra' - Garret Birkoff, and Saunders Mac Lane in Section 1.9.

I'm an autodidact and there are no answers in the back so I need you guys to look at my proofs every once in a while to verify them. As you might be able to tell from my previous posts my mathematical maturity is not too high so I appreciate your patience. I give you permission to laugh at 
[this post from 6 months ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684491/prove-a-1a-ive-done-two-possible-proofs-which-is-valid-if-at-all) but I'm getting better.

The truth of the congruence 
$X^2 \equiv 35 \pmod{100}$ can be inferred from looking at $100|(x^2-35)$ which has the equivalent of saying $100k = x^2 -35$ for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$

by basic algebra $ x^2 =100k + 35 $ which I will now write as a function of k and attempt an induction.

Let

$P(k) = 100k + 35$

$P(0) = 35$ which is not a square.

$P(k+1) = 100(k + 1) + 35 = 100k + 100 +35 = (100k + 35) + 100$

by substitution from the induction hypothesis
$ P(0) + 100 = 35 + 100 = 135 $

which is also not a square. Q.E.D.

Comment: Using the induction hypothesis you get $P(k+1) = P(k) + 100$.

Comment: Not following.  Suppose you were asked about $x^2=21\pmod {100}$.  Wouldn't your argument work here as well?  But $x=11$ is a solution.

Comment: As a (sketch of an) easy approach to this, suppose $n$ were a solution.  Then $n^2=100k+35$.  Using the fact that $5\,|\,n^2\iff 5\,|\,n$ note that $25$ divides two of the terms, hence we must have $25\,|\,35$, a contradiction.

Comment: When dealing with arithmetical tasks you should attempt to factor things as much as possible: $x^2=100k+35$ implies $x^2=5(20k+7)$, hence $5|x$, write $x=5m$ and plug it back to get $5m^2=20k+7$, which factors as $5(m^2-4k) = 7$. Thus $5|7$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$X^2=100k+35=4(25k)+35=4(25k+8)\color{red}{+3}$.

Comment: So what does it imply sir?

Comment: You are supposed to know that squares cannot have just any old residue modulo 4.  Hence, my red marking.

Comment: @CloudJR Squares can only leave remainder $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$ (why?), so $100k+35$ cannot be a square for any $k$ since it always leaves remainder $3$ when divided by $4$.

Comment: @ovi  because square of an even number is divisible by 4 and square odd number gives remainder 1 or 9 (which is 1).Thanks for your help!@oscar Lanzi and ovi

Comment: @OscarLanzi This fact was not mentioned in my book. I wonder if the author intended for me to solve it differently. Does your technique have a name? I'd like to know more about it.

Comment: @PossiblyDakota If you look up Quadratic Residues you may find out how to solve $x^2 = k \pmod n$. However, that is more complicated; the fact that any square is either $0$ or $1$ $\pmod 4$ it is just a basic fact that you too will just know after studying this subject for some time; you can do a similar argument mod different things. For example, any number $x$ is either $0$, $1$
, or $2 \pmod 3$. Thus $x^2$ is either $0^2 = 0$, $1^2 = 1$, or $2^2 = 1$; so squares cannot be $2 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 5):

$100k+35$ is divisible by 5, so if it is a perfect square $a^2$, then $a$ is divisible by 5 too. But $a$ cannot be multiple of 10. On the other hand $(10b+5)^2=100b^2+100b+25$ which does not end in 35 either.

Answer (score 3):

If $ x^2 = 100*n + 35 $ which is multiple of 5, so x would be also multiple of 5. 
The left hand side would be multiple of 25, but the right hand side is $ 25*(4*n+1)+10 $ which 
is not multiple of 25. Hence the equation has no solutions.

Comment: You aught to format your post. See this link https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference